# How can I commit and push to someone else's repository on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repository created by a professor on my virtual machine (I'm running Ubuntu 13.10) and we're supposed to create personal folders. I created mine, but I cannot for the life of me commit and push it to make it show up on GitHub. I swear I have tried every answer on here, and things have improved somewhat. For instance, I originally had a version of Git that was too old and wouldn't permit https. I also created a blank file in my personal directory because I know GitHub doesn't store empty folders.

I originally cloned the repository using:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/astrofoley/astr596.git
```

And then used

```
git config --global user.name "myusername"
```

and

```
git config --global user.email "myemail"
```

I checked with my professor and he made sure I have adequate permissions.

At this point, depending upon which commit and push methods I use (I always try to push to https://github.com/astrofoley/astr596.git), I get several different errors ranging from "nothing added to commit but untracked files present" to simply "403". I have no idea what I am doing wrong, but I suspect it is something related to the fact that the repository belongs to another account. Either way, this is getting incredibly frustrating. Please help!

EDIT: Here's an example of my current problem. I tried adding and committing the file in my directory again using

```
git add blank.txt
```

(this step seems to have worked fine) and then

```
git commit blank.txt
```

At this point I get the message "On branch master, nothing to commit, working directory clean".

Comment: are you not even able to commit in your local repo? If you cloned the repository in your machine you are able to do whatever you want locally. Pushing would be another thing

Comment: have you changed something in blank.txt? which is the output of `git status`?

Comment: I finally got the full commit prompt (where it asked for my commit message) at some point last night but I think it got canceled somehow and I can't see to get back to it now.

Comment: then you have no change yet. Do following: -modify blank.txt -type `git status`, it should output the change `-git add --all`, should add this change to the stagging area -`git commit -m "message"`, should commit your changes. If you now take a look at your commit trees you should have it there

Comment: It says modify is not a command. I just deleted blank.txt and created a new file called test.txt and it let me commit it. Now how do I push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESOLVED. I deleted and recloned the directory now that I have collaborator permissions. This was definitely the way to go because it removed the failed ssh keys and all of the different configurations I'd been experimenting with. Once everything was recloned, I re-made my directory, put a blank file in it, git added the directory and then the file, committed my change from the astr596 repository, and pushed to origin. Success!

Answer (score 5):

Just to make it comprehensive,

1. Make a change.

   ```
   touch somefile.txt
   ```
2. tell git to track this change

   ```
   git add somefile.txt
   ```
3. commit the change

   ```
   git commit -m "what you did"
   ```
4. [set up your remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote).
5. push

   ```
   git push <remote> <branch>
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely getting closer. When I do this, it says the tip of my branch is behind its remote counterpart. I tried the pull command and it says it made everything up to date but its still giving me an error. I don't think I understand the branch syntax. If I want to push astr596/personal/Rebecca to the remote, what should <branch> look like?

Comment: I think that you probably need to read just a bit about git. Trying to do these things before understanding what you are doing is a little dangerous. I would check out Pro-git, it is free and available online. Specifically, check out [this page](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) which might help clear this up. Glad to see it is resolved, you should accept your answer to mark this as closed.

Comment: Done! Thank you. I will be sure to read more about it -- this project was just time-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Are you added as a collaborator in your professor's repo? If you are working from a linux terminal you must give your professor a [id_rsa.pub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-linux) file to add you as collaborator (since the terminal is not synced with your github account, which actually happens if you use the GUI versions of github for win or mac).

Other option is to fork his repo into your account, clone it from there to your PC and then send "pull request" to the original repo.

Comment: He just added me this morning, so that part should be in order. He keeps insisting that I should be able to use https and I think a few people have been able to, so I'm wary of generating ssh keys. If I fork his repo into my account, how do I push to my fork?

Comment: Well, as I understand your teacher added your Github account to the repo, and you are working from a terminal (not github Gui). If that's the case, you still need to add your id_rsa.pub into your Github account ... is not enough to declare your email (git config --global user.email "myemail").

Comment: Setting up ssh keys appeared to be working until I got this error, which is apparently common with Jaunty. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/201786